# How to reroute the connector in visio programmatically?

Tags: c#, vba, visio

I'm developing VSTO add-in for visio 2013. I need to reroute the connector, for the diagram is complex and consists lots of steps. The automatically routed connector doesn't have a clear path. Is there any way available to reroute the connector programmatically? Just like draging the connector points in visio application manually.

I read some vba documents
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.connect
but none gives me insight.

Comment: Dynamic connector managed by Visio application core, we haven't any documentation how it works! You can reroute "correctly (just as you need)" route, but Visio core can change you changes, and create new path !

Comment: So, you mean after my change to the Dynamic connector, Visio application core is possible to change it ultimately? Furthermore, is there any samples or documents about rerouting Dynamic connector?

Comment: Yes, Visio core can change route of connector ! You can read same [russian speaking thread via Google Translate](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ru&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=http://visio.getbb.ru/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D6%26t%3D956%26st%3D0%26sk%3Dt%26sd%3Da%26sid%3Dba112c935a8271e90f06f61ec456fc78&xid=25657,15700021,15700186,15700190,15700248,15700253&usg=ALkJrhjr69dqWZ7-JDS6zrGChFULT9jVsA)

Comment: You can programatically re-layout the page, which will force all connectors onto a clear path. It can result in some spaghetti-looking diagrams, but that can be minimized by being smart about the order that you drop shapes in. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I've also had some success by separating my shapes into groupings based on whether I want them to be automatically re-positioned or fixed in place. This can do a lot to clean up the connector lines.

Comment: Thanks you both. SmrtGrunt, you really inspired me with a new approach. But I still want to figure out how to route a dynamic connector's path, I mean, like besides the points of fromShape and toShape, define some points for the dynamic connector, then it's path will be a line that path all those points sequentially. And Surrogate, thanks for your link, I'm going to take a look after finish my job. Sorry for the delay, I'm busy recently.

Comment: @stevenchuh I ended up taking a crack at it below. Let me know if you've got any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inspired me to take a crack at this, since I need to do something similar.
Here's a way that I found to make it work. This subroutine takes a reference to a connector shape, hides the automatically-routed line, adds a new geometry section, and manually adjusts several points within that section (based on the percentage height/width of the originally-visible line). You can obviously adjust quantities / locations programatically.

```
Sub CustomRoutedConnector(shpConnectorShape As Shape)

    With shpConnectorShape
        'Hide the automatically routed connector line (still there, just hidden)
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent, 0, 2).FormulaU = "TRUE"

        'Make a custom geometry section
        .AddSection visSectionFirstComponent + 1
        .AddRow visSectionFirstComponent + 1, visRowComponent, visTagComponent
        .AddRow visSectionFirstComponent + 1, visRowVertex, visTagLineTo
        .AddRow visSectionFirstComponent + 1, visRowVertex, visTagMoveTo

        'Set up the new geometry section rows (11,1 and 11,2 are the start and end rows)
        .CellsSRC(11, 0, 0).FormulaForceU = "TRUE"
        .CellsSRC(11, 0, 1).FormulaForceU = "FALSE"
        .CellsSRC(11, 0, 2).FormulaForceU = "FALSE"
        .CellsSRC(11, 0, 3).FormulaForceU = "FALSE"
        .CellsSRC(11, 0, 5).FormulaForceU = "FALSE"
        .CellsSRC(11, 1, 0).FormulaU = "0"
        .CellsSRC(11, 1, 1).FormulaU = "0"
        .CellsSRC(11, 2, 0).FormulaU = "0"
        .CellsSRC(11, 2, 1).FormulaU = "0"

        'Add two additional rows for demonstration (could be programatically 
        'adjusted to however many points you need)

        .AddRow visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 2, visTagLineTo
        .CellsSRC(11, 2, 0).FormulaU = "0"
        .CellsSRC(11, 2, 1).FormulaU = "0"

        .AddRow visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 3, visTagLineTo
        .CellsSRC(11, 3, 0).FormulaU = "0"
        .CellsSRC(11, 3, 1).FormulaU = "0"

        'Adjust the geometry of the rows (the doubles given are percentages of the height/width of the original connector)
        'I recommend stepping through this to see how it moves the points:
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 2, 0).FormulaU = ".5"
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 3, 0).FormulaU = ".5"
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 3, 1).FormulaU = ".5"
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 4, 0).FormulaU = "1"
        .CellsSRC(visSectionFirstComponent + 1, 4, 1).FormulaU = "1"

    End With

End Sub
```

The end points of this custom route are still tied to the start and end shapes. To completely kill all automatic routing, use the `.LayoutRoutePassive` [property of the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.page.layoutroutepassive). (This might give you what you're looking for, but it would take some tinkering).

Comment: For some reason the code highlighting is not great here, but it should copy/paste just fine.

Comment: Thanks for concering my question so much. The answer you gave is great. However, this questing was one of the uncertain points in my fesibility test. And now, it shows too much difficulties to resolve. I stored you answer, and if the same demand occurs again, I will take a deep look at it.

Comment: @stevenchuh No worries. I hope it helps you or somebody else in the future.